# Difficulty in using sympy solver in python

Tags: python, sympy

Please run the following code

```
    from sympy.solvers import solve
    from sympy import Symbol
    x = Symbol('x')
    R2 = solve(-109*x**5/3870720+4157*x**4/1935360-3607*x**3/69120+23069*x**2/60480+5491*x/2520+38-67,x)
    print R2
```

The output of the code is

> [2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3 - 184552*x**2 -
>   527136*x + 3507840, 0), 2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3
>   - 184552*x**2 - 527136*x + 3507840, 1), 2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3 - 184552*x**2 - 527136*x + 3507840, 2),
>   2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3 - 184552*x**2 -
>   527136*x + 3507840, 3), 2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3
>   - 184552*x**2 - 527136*x + 3507840, 4)]

Can someone explain what the answer represent and how to get the output in conventional form i.e. say if  the answer is `0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.4` sympy usually outputs the answer as `[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get numerical approximations in an answer, you can use N(). Since you have multiple solutions, you can loop through the list. I have used an easier equation since yours takes a while ...

Try this:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve

from sympy import Symbol, N
x = Symbol('x')
#R2 = solve(-109*x**5/3870720+4157*x**4/1935360-3607*x**3/69120+23069*x**2/60480+5491*x/2520+38-67,x)
R2 = solve(x**2+2*x-4,x)
print R2
print [N(solution) for solution in R2]
```

[EDIT]: As mentioned in the comments below, the fifth order equation can only be solved after upgrading sympy (to 1.0 in my case).

Comment: Thanks but if you could explain what the answers meant for e.g. 2*CRootOf(109*x*\*5 - 4157*x*\*4 + 50498*x*\*3 - 184552*x*\*2 - 527136*x + 3507840, 0)

Comment: How long have you waited for a result? Did not get any within 20 sec.

Comment: There seems to be a problem, on my laptop it isn't taking much but on my friend's laptop it is taking 31.48 seconds

Comment: I don't get anyything within 2 minutes. I only get results after I delete your fifth and fourth order term. My PC isn't that bad. Strange, sorry, I am out of the loop for your second question.

Comment: To improve the speed try updating the sympy version, my friend also updated sympy to version 1.0 and got results in seconds(already mentioned that he got it in 31.48 sec earlier).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to upgrade sympy, works for my now. So what is the problem? After the upgrade, I do get the results listed above. CRootOf means "cubic root of", so this is before duing the numeric approcimation.. So you could write CRootOf(8) instead of 2.

Comment: The C in CRootOf stands for "complex".

Answer (score 3):

SymPy's `solve` only gives symbolic solutions. `CRootOf` is a way of symbolically representing roots of polynomials whose roots can't be represented by radicals. If you are only interested in numeric solutions, you can use `N` on each of the terms as suggested by @tfv, or use `nsolve`, which solves the equation numerically. In general symbolic `solve` may be overkill if you only care about numeric solutions.