# Python Sympy : Why can't it find the root of the equation

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving

I am trying to find the real root of the 5th degree equation shown below. As a result of the solution, there are 4 imaginary and 1 real root, but I found this solution in a different way. I couldn't get it using python sympy. What could be the reason and how can I solve this in python?

```
x_pt = -3
y_pt = 3

x = sym.symbols("x" , real = True)

f = (x-3)**3

n= 1 /sym.diff(f,x)

eqn = sym.Eq(y_pt , f + -n * (x_pt - x))

x_roots = sym.solve(eqn)

print(x_roots)
```

The print is

```
[CRootOf(3*x**5 - 45*x**4 + 270*x**3 - 819*x**2 + 1270*x - 807, 0)]
```

I know root is `x ≈ 2.278` but Python can not give this number. It gives expression above weirdly !

How can I solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[sym.N(i) for i in sym.solve(eqn, check=False)]
```

outputs:

```
[2.27811833988274,
 2.29407705823809 - 1.36417683043667*I,
 2.29407705823809 + 1.36417683043667*I,
 4.06686377182054 - 0.190009600377279*I,
 4.06686377182054 + 0.190009600377279*I]
```

or, without `check=False`,

`[sym.N(i) for i in sym.solve(eqn)]` outputs `[2.27811833988274]`

Got this from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36811640/11574713

Answer (score 0):

The CRootOf object is a representation you can use to further work with the result.
If you just want to get one of the possible results you can evaluate the expression:

e.g. up to a certain precision

```py
# ...
x_roots = sym.solve(eqn)
print(x_roots[0].eval_approx(10))
```

for full reference see (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.rootoftools.ComplexRootOf.eval_approx)